# What is the GitLab proj_id_hash for the bucket structure in the object store?

Tags: gitlab

In this [document covering the Feature Bucket](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/development/uploads/working_with_uploads.md#feature-bucket-details), it says, the Bucket Structure for the Job Artifacts is

```
/artifacts/<proj_id_hash>/<date>/<job_id>/<artifact_id>
```

In the above, what is the `<proj_id_hash>`? There is only a `ci_project_mirrors` table (no `ci_projects`), and it does not have a hash column it only has 3 columns for `id`, `project_id`, and `namespace_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## sha256sum of the Project ID

The `proj_id_hash` is the hash of the project id. It doesn't exist in the database. If your project id `4242` you would

```
echo -n 4242 | sha256sum
```